# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in footer.php

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/.../public_html/lagatar.com/wp-content/themes/.../footer.php on line

Above error is appearing below my site's footer after I added facebook's code for likebox in my footer.php.

```
<?php

/* Prevent direct access to this file */
if ( !defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR') )
    die('Please do not access this file directly.');

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=204491109624023&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

/* WordPress and a lot of plugins require the function in this file, so I guess we have to use it :-(. */
wp_footer();


Display::body_close();

Display::html_close();
```

Comment: The backticks to format blocks of code are unnecessary - just use the code button.

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally inserted your HTML within the PHP tags, you should do it rather this way:

```
<?php    
/* Prevent direct access to this file */ if ( !defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR') )  die('Please do not access this file directly.');    
?>

<div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=204491109624023&version=v2.0"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<?php    
/* WordPress and a lot of plugins require the function in this file, so I guess we have to use it :-(. */ 
wp_footer();

Display::body_close();

Display::html_close();
```

Comment: your code removed the error. but the fb like box is not appearing properly (only a small portion of it is visible). [please look at bottom right corner of my site]. fyi: fb comments is also having same appearance issue. previously both likebox n comments were fine but with that parse error. @Grzegorz Pawlik

Comment: Your current problem is the size of the FB box. Its rendering good but there are some CSS rules that override its size. You can fix it with the following code: .widget_text .fb_iframe_widget iframe { width:300px !important; height:240px !important }

Comment: i added that. now fb likebox is playing hide n seek. it only appears when i scroll down. and what about fb comment? only small portion of it is visible. i dont know what is creating all these issues... FYI; all site changes i made was minification n some other stuffs to improve pagespeed. also look at my recentposts/mostviewed... image thumbnail is supposed to be there but it's not there. In short: As far as i know, fb likebox, fb comments & that recentpost/most viewed plugin started having problem at the same time after i did something wrong (don't know what i did!) @Grzegorz Pawlik